# How To Create a Reusable Grid that Angular components can be passed into

Tags: angular, css-grid, angular-components, angular-library

I have been searching for not just an answer, but what the "Angular Way" is to do it.

Th end goal is to have a css-grid component in a library that I am able to pass components into to populate. Something like this:

`grid-component-in-library.html`

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>
```

`grid-component-in-library.scss`

```
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And then, the consuming app would be able to pass components into this grid to populate:

`consuming-app.component.html`

```
    <grid-component-in-library item1=client-side-header-component item2="client-side-menu-component" etc etc>
    or would they be passed in via the body of the reusable library component?
    <client-side-header-component></client-side-header-component>
    ...etc
    </grid-component-in-library>
```

Basically, something similar to what Angular Material Grid does, without having to use Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

Comment: I created a datatable component [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/datatable) which can be used [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables/datatables.component.html). Demo is [here](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/datatables). It allows custom rows and column headers

Comment: Maybe my phrasing isn't correct. Is reusable template a better word instead of reusable grid? I'm not referring to data tables, but rather the entire layout. Using  css-grid perhaps. But I'm not sure how to pass components into the grid, or if there is a better way.

Comment: You'll probably need [ng-content](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#single-slot-content-projection)